# View all jobs by company x does not apply "search" filter when inside of a job listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Within jobs do a search for "dba" you get something like this:

[image]

Now from this listing above if I click on **Jr. MS SQL Server DBA** it will take me to the job listing page with links at the top to go to the previous job listing, in this case **Web Application Developer** and the next job listing, in this case **Senior Database Developer / Administrator**, as shown:

[image]

Now try something different.  Go to a company page like so:

1. Click the tab search companies
2. Enter they keyword Quicken Loans
3. Select the first result Quicken Loans
4. Select any job from their open jobs https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/quicken-loans#jobs
5. Scroll all the way down on the job listing page to find a link **<< view all Quicken Loans job listings**
6. You are presented with 5 quicken-loan jobs filtered

Now within these 5 if I select one I would expect similar behavior as mentioned before. So here are the jobs:

[image]

If I click from the above image the job **Data Warehouse Engineer** I would expect links to the prior job **Progress Software Engineer** and a link to the next job **Software Engineer**, instead clicking **Data Warehouse Engineer** gives me this:

[image]

Totally different company and different position.  The filtered jobs are not really filtered at this point...however if I click the **<< search results** link on the left (under the search jobs tab).  I'm taken back to my results for quicken, then I click the **Search** button and now I can click on a job and see the correct behavior.

There is some sort of bug here that not maintaining the list of jobs when you are on a job listing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report. I've spent some time to eliminate a bunch of edge cases around job search to make all of this consistent. Hopefully this should be the last of the weirdness!